# differentiate delimeter

Tags: java, nodes, delimiter

i want to read some data from a text file.for example:

1 // total 1 client data

192.168.1.116;pc3;/home/pc3/Documents;C:/user/windows/Desktop; // details of client data.

and this is my code:

```
String strLine;
String [] values = new String[4];
int counter = 0;
int clientCounter = 0;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
// Print the content on the console
String delims = ";";
String[] tokens = strLine.split(delims);
if(counter == 0)//Reading total clients
{                       
    totalClient = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    counter++;
}
else
{   
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{
values[i] = tokens[i];  
}
dc = new DisplayClient(clientCounter,values[0],values[1]," ",values[2],values[3]);
clientList.add(dc);
```

but now the file that i need to read have few delimiters. For example:

0:1,0.5,2,0.7,3,0.2; // 7 items

1:0,0.5,7,1;//5 items

2:0,0.7;// 3 items

i am using this data to create a p2p simulation.

2:0,0.7;//means Node 2 is connected to Node 0 with bandwidth 700kbps

1:0,0.5,7,1;//means Node 1 is connected to Node 0 with 500kbps and Node 1 is also connected to Node 7 with 1000kbps(1mbps).

but now it have 3 delimiters and the item of node maybe be static. It might be 3 items or 5 items or 7 items or might be more. how can i read this and let differentiate each data with delimiter ??

Sorry for my ignorance and thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

1. Keep one routing per line but drop the semicolon.
2. Delimit the routing up by commas and colons instead of semicolons.
3. Load the first int (it is your source node)
4. Iteratively load your next pair of ints (they are your destination nodes and speeds).

Comment: now i able to read the files. but if i want to make a 2d graph to present the data, what method can i use ? a 2d graph something like a node connected to a node

Comment: Glad you can read files now. You already have 2d in a sense. Looks to me that you have all the syntax you need for a directed, acyclic graph.

Answer (score 1):

I would represent the data a little differently:

1:0,0.5;7,1;n,s;.......

1.Split the line on ":" and set the source node to first element of array.

2.Split second entry by ";" and iterate over resulting array, each entry would represent a node and for each one you can split it on "," and get the node number and speed.

3.For each source node you now have all connected nodes and their speeds regardless of the number of their number.